# Git-Submodule dependencies vs. Visual Studio dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, git-submodules

I do have the following respsitory dependencies:

[image]

Using submodules clonging `Repo 1` recursivly (`git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 {repo-path}`) would add the following folder structure to my drive:

[image]

Of course I have a clone of the `Repo 2` somewhere else, where I use to develope the project inside `Repo 2`.
So, open the project inside `Repo 2` in visual studios there I would have a solution containing both projects of `Repo 2` and `Repo 4`, whereas `Repo 2` will get a dependency assigned to the project from `Repo 4`.

The same for the solution when developing on the project in `Repo 3` that depends on the project in `Repo 4` as well.

When I set up the visual studio solution for the "Application" project (i.e. `Repo 4`) I would have to add all projects from each repositorie once (only once as the IDE obviously doesn't take the same projects twice, so far so clear). This means that only 1 of 3 possible `Repo 4` projects will be added (so lets choose that one that came with `Repo 1`).

Now the problem occurs, where I have to reassign the dependency path of `Repo 2` and `Repo 3` to that other `Repo 4` that came with `Repo 1`. This consequently will affect the project file of these repositories which leads to the request to commit that new path which I don't want of course!

So how do you handle this issue as I guess that this isn't a rare problem (correct me if I am wrong).

*And as every time: If you dislike it feel free to -1 it, but leave a comment below why. Else its simply discouraging.*

Comment: No one has any idea?? I can't be the only one that ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> So how do you handle this issue as I guess that this isn't a rare problem

It is a problem that is generally actively avoided.

"`git submodule`" suggests source dependencies, as opposed to binary dependencies

The workarounds are:

- depend on binary only, meaning you depend on Repo4 built artifact (like a dll or library), not on Repo4 source (which would involve cloning)
- monorepository approach, where all projects are in the same repository, with symlinks in order Repo2 or Repo3 to point to the same Repo4.